# JS - map() ranking in a table

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is gonna be one of the easiest questions you'll see on here today, I'm sure of it

The API I'm calling, lists the assets from greatest (first) to least (last) and I'm trying to rank or add an increment of 1 for every row rendered. How can I rank the assets as I'm trying to do?

var a = 1;

and {a + 1} renders 2 for each field.

```
  if ((typeof datalol !== "undefined") 
           && datalol !== null) {

    const coins = datalol.getCoins.coins;
    for(let i = 0, l = coins.length; i < l; i++) {
      var rows = coins.map((coin: any) => {
        var a = 1;
        return {

        cells: [                
          {
            key: 'rank',
            content: (
            <p>{a + 1}</p>
            ),
          },
          {
            key: 'symbol',
            content: (
              <span style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <p><b>{coin.symbol.toUpperCase()}</b></p>
              </span>
            ),
          },
          {
            key: 'name',
            content: (
              <span style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <p style={{ fontSize: 12}}>{coin.name}</p>
              </span>
            ),
          }
        ],
      };
    })
  }};
```

[image]

[image]

edit: I guess i = 249

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: Can you please share some raw dump of data that you get from 'datalol.getCoins.coins'?I am a bit concerned about iterating with map() which overwrites the 'rows' variable inside the loop which (probably unnecessarily) runs coins.length times. The value you get (250) is the last value of i after the outer for loop ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the api provides me with the ranking xD

Calling coins.market_cap_rank is so much easier than trying to calculate this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make it as `i+1` instead of `a+1`. also remove declaration of `a` as it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `var a =1` inside of an `[].map`. This will cause `a` to be initialized with `1` every time. You have three options here. Also, you don't need `for` loop here as you are just iterating the same thing with `map()` which is `datalol.getCoins.coins`. What you can do is, just use `map()`'s key as ranking.

```js
coins.map((coin: any, a: number) => {
        return {

        cells: [                
          {
            key: 'rank',
            content: (
            <p>{a + 1}</p>
            ),
          },
          {
            key: 'symbol',
            content: (
              <span style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <p><b>{coin.symbol.toUpperCase()}</b></p>
              </span>
            ),
          },
          {
            key: 'name',
            content: (
              <span style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <p style={{ fontSize: 12}}>{coin.name}</p>
              </span>
            ),
          }
        ],
      };
    })
```

You can read more about `map()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)